# Jquery adding span after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi how it is possible to add a new selector and replace the current one to a link that has been clicked? 
following are my link before the click:

```
<a href="#">Date</a>
```

link after click:

```
<span title="" class="i-wrap ig-wrap-common i-sort-descend-common-wrap ig-wrap-common-r selected whatsthis"><i class="i ig-common i-sort-descend-common"></i> Date </span>
```

Following are my html snippet for above link:

```
<div id="review_sort_section" class="ieSucks">Sort by:


                <a href="#">Date</a>
             | 
                <a href="#">Rating</a>
             | 

    </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @AleksandrM many but all mess up, so i only post the question as simple as can, if i receive any solutions i can compare with mine which didn't work well

Comment: We are not going to write code for you. Show what you got so far and someone will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#review_sort_section a').click(function() {
    var span = '<span title="" class="i-wrap ig-wrap-common i-sort-descend-common-wrap ig-wrap-common-r selected whatsthis"><i class="i ig-common i-sort-descend-common"></i>' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
    $(this).replaceWith(span);
});
```

Here is a demo with updated requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/DDCbe/

Comment: when click neighbor link the previous is still with span selector

Comment: Then you should have specified it. Moment..

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: now that's helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('#review_sort_section a').click(function(){
    var new_content='<span title="" class="i-wrap ig-wrap-common i-sort-descend-common-wrap ig-wrap-common-r selected whatsthis"><i class="i ig-common i-sort-descend-common"></i> Date </span>';
    $(this).replaceWith(new_content);
 });
});
```